# Using sprintf with unicode characters

Tags: c, unicode

I wanted to print out depictions of playing cards using Unicode.

Code snippet:

```
void printCard(int card){
    char strCard[10];
    sprintf(strCard, "\U0001F0A%x", (card%13)+1);
    printf("%s\n", cardStr);
}
```

Since the \U requires 8 hex characters after it I get the following from compiling:

`error: incomplete universal character name \U0001F0A`

I could create a bunch of if/else statements and print out the card that way but I was hoping for a way that wouldn't make me explicitly write out every card's Unicode encoding.

Comment: Use `swprintf` etc and use wide characters. Save the source as uni code and prefix strings with L

Comment: Can't you just compute the code point as a wchar_t? Even so I'd be surprised if printf printed that correctly - which environment are you in?

Comment: What unicode encoding do you use? Modern editors use UTF8. Note that the compiler must be configured appropriately for the input charset and the output charset. gcc for instance uses utf-8, too by default for both. However, you can change both by an option. For internal chars, you would require the appropriate type (not sure if `wchar_t` is correct for any encoding and for char-arrays (vulgo: "strings") ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Universal character names (like `\U0001F0A1`) are resolved by the compiler. If you use one in a format string, `printf` will see the UTF-8 representation of the character; it has no idea how to handle backslash escapes. (The same is true of `\n` and `\x2C`; those are single characters resolved by the compiler.) So you certainly cannot compute the UCN at runtime.

The most readable solution would be to use an array of strings to hold the 13 different card symbols.

That will avoid hard-wiring knowledge about Unicode and UTF-8 encoding into the program. If you knew that the active locale was a UTF-8 locale, you could compute the codepoints as a `wchar_t` and the use wide-character-to-multibyte standard library functions to produce the UTF-8 version. But I'm not at all convinced that it would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty UTF-8 solution:

```
void printCard(int card) {
    printf("\xF0\x9F\x82%c\n", 0xA1 + card % 13);
}
```

The UTF-8 representation of `\U0001F0A1` is `F0 9F 82 A1`.  The above code will correctly handle all 13 cards, if your terminal supports UTF-8 and non-BMP code points, like iTerm2 on OS/X.

Alternative solutions involving wide-char conversion to multibyte character sets are complicated to use and would not work on platforms where `wchar_t` is limited to 16 bits.